# Add qlr group layer definition to existing QGIS map document

Tags: qgis, qlr

I am able to drag and drop a .qlr group layer definition into new QGIS map projects prior to a first save, but when I drag and drop a .qlr file into a map project in QGIS after the initial save, none of the data or styles are added to the map. The names of the layers in the group appear in the browser panel, but the layers and styles are gone. Does anyone know of a solution to this problem? I am using QGIS 2.18.3.

Comment: If you can change a bit the use case (i.e., no need to save and load QLR files manually), you could use the "Copy layers and groups to clipboard" plugin and get your layers (with styles) copied into other projects. http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CopyLayersAndGroupsToClipboard/